# why is this forEach() var not resolving?

Tags: javascript

I have some code which:

1. gets all id's from a js array of objects
2. creates a distinct list of those id's into a new variable
3. does a `forEach` against the distinct list of ids for 1-by-1 processing

```
let commodityIds = supplierPricingInfo.map(x => x.CommodityId);
let distinctCommodityIds = [...new Set(commodityIds)];
distinctCommodityIds.forEach(x => {
    sapCommodityRows = supplierPricingInfo.filter(x => x.CommodityId === x);
    debugger;
});
```

When my code hits the debugger breakpoint above, a forEach x value of 2 shows in the watch but no matching rows are returned from supplierPricingInfo (although there should be).  However, if I hardcode the `x` variable value to 2 then matching rows are returned from supplierPricingInfo.  This is pretty weird.  I don't think I've seen an issue like this before.  Any idea what the root cause might be?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `x`'s are mixed up. Try replacing the outer `x` with `id`, like this:

```
distinctCommodityIds.forEach(id => {
  sapCommodityRows = supplierPricingInfo.filter(x => x.CommodityId === id);
  debugger;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this, here we get the unique CommodityId from array.

```
let items = [
  { id: 1, CommodityId: 1, name: 'Alex' },
  { id: 2, CommodityId: 2, name: 'John' },
  { id: 3, CommodityId: 1, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 4, CommodityId: 3, name: 'Doe' },
  { id: 5, CommodityId: 2, name: 'Peter' }
];

const unique = [...new Set(items.map(item => item.CommodityId))];
console.log(unique)
```